# No chance to transfer ETH from contract to address whatever gas I set

Tags: solidity, gas, transfer

I looked through suggested similar tickets. Not my case.

The problem is that I can't transfer ETH from contract to any address:

`(bool success1, ) = payable(recipients[index]).call{value: uint256(amount), gas: 1e6}("");`

After execution `success1` is always true, but ETH never comes to destination.

[image: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc83e9c3818d3769b65108f03b9da73d09ac0ab88cbc17a7ca6b67efa113386e8]

Also it shows at the etherscan the value is 0, but in fact it is 0.0095 ETH. Which is proven by the consecutive event emitted. Solidity v8.4.0.

What I am doing wrong here?

**Resolved**:
Basically 1GWei was not enough. I read several articles and all of them stated that 1GWei is more then enough for all cases, appeared - not. Increased to 1E9 and trnx took 7 GWei.

**But still, why it responds with true on failed transfer? Can I catch that somehow?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the recipient a contract? Is a 'new' address? (ie it hasn't been used previously). `call` only returns false if recipient's callback has reverted otherwise it will return true. Etherscan only shows the transferred values if the transaction was successful. Unfortunately without more details it is just a guess.

Comment: The recipient is a vault address not a contract. But I seems your answer is accurate enough. If no revert then it always true. But is there a way to understand the transfer was successful?

Comment: If call returns true the transfer has succeeded. It might be that after the call there's another error that causes a revert, in that case the revert will undo any operation, storage modifications, transfers, etc will return to the state before the transaction execution.